# How to refresh a script after some time using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There is a variable I want to update  every minute.

So am curious whether there is a way in Javascript where I can refresh the whole script after some time instead of the variable itself.

```
<script> 

function vName(){
 videos = $('#videos').text();
}

 vName();
```

Comment: what do you mean by refreshing whole script?
Do you mean refreshing the page?
Do you mean calling vName() function after some time?

Comment: Have you tried `setInterval()` method?

Comment: Why don’t you want to just update the variable? The only way to refresh the entire script is to reload the page, which will also restart the video.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval`. Here hello will print each and every 3sec

```js
setInterval(function(){ console.log("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achive this using an event to listen to the element's change:

```js
(function () {
 "use strict";
 let videos = '';
        $("#videos").on("change", evt => {
           videos = $(evt.target).val();
           console.log(videos);
        });
})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="videos" type="text">
```

Comment: he meant using JS

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Set interval is a function which is being used to perform any functionality after a specific desired time span . The function is always called again and again after that time period . The below code is an example for setInterval.

### Code:-

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Video is here "); }, 9000);
```

### Explanation

you can call any method in place of "alert("Video is here")" and the desired time period is being given in place of "9000" that means the specific function is  being called after every 9 seconds

Answer (score -1):

You can put your code in `setInterval()` function, like this

```
setInterval(()=>{

//your script here
 function vName(){
 videos = $('#videos').text();
}
 vName();

}, 60000);
```